# Only update messages when there is a connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I built a site display messages, so the msgloader.js updates the messages every 10 seconds from admin. The client displays this site on a screen constantly.

The problem is that sometimes the internet connection is not so good, the display got disconnected and the msgloader.js still updates the messages, in the end the screen freeze (the reason I know is that there is a clock on the site as well, the clock gets time from the local machine, it simply freeze at a time until we refresh the page which is an issue).

I suspect this freeze issue is because there is too much script running and the machine ram has been taken up.

BACK TO THE QUESTION, Is there any way we can set the below code into update messages every 10 seconds when there is an internet connection, otherwise update messages every hour/two when there is no internet connection.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Update the data for the static sections
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function updateSection(sect) 
{   
    setTimeout('updateSection(' + sect + ')', 10000);

    //alert('updateSection: ' + sect);
    var ajax = new sack();
    ajax.requestFile = 'ajax/getMessages.php?section='+sect;
    ajax.method = 'post';
    /*ajax.onError = whenError;*/
    ajax.onCompletion = whenComplete;
    ajax.runAJAX();

/*  function whenError() 
    {
        alert('Could not return getMessages values. <br />Please notify the system administrator.');
    }*/

    function whenComplete() 
    {
        var messages = ajax.response;

        var messages1 = messages.split('---');

        var num_messages    = messages1[0];
        //alert('Num Lines: ' + num_messages );
        var messages_list   = messages1[1];
        //alert('MESSAGES: '+messages);
        var msg_data_array  = messages_list.split('::');

        var i=0;            
        switch(sect)
        {
            case 1:

                for(i=0;i<=num_messages;i++)
                {

                    var j = i + 1;
                    icon_to_use = 'icon'+j;

                    // Set icon class
                    var icon = document.getElementById('icon_' + sect + '_' + j);
                    icon_to_use.className = 'icon_pointer';

                    // Set message text
                    // -------------------------------------------                  
                    var msgtext_array = msg_data_array[i].split('##');


                    // Here's the title
                    // -------------------------------------------
                    var msgtext_1a = msgtext_array[1];


                    // Here's the text
                    // -------------------------------------------
                    var msgtext_1 = msgtext_array[2];

                    // Set the title space
                    // -------------------------------------------
                    var msg_1a = document.getElementById('msg_text_' + sect + '_' + j + 'a');

                    // Set the text space
                    // -------------------------------------------
                    var msg_1 = document.getElementById('msg_text_' + sect + '_' + j);

                    // Write in the title
                    // -------------------------------------------                      
                    msg_1a.innerHTML = msgtext_1a;
                     msg_1.innerHTML = "<img src='[url_of_image]' /> " + msgtext_1;
                    // Write in the text
                    // -------------------------------------------                      
                    msg_1.innerHTML = (msgtext_1) ? separator + msgtext_1 : msgtext_1;

                    //msg_1a.style.borderBottom="2px solid white";
                    msg_1a.style.borderBottom="2px solid white";
                    msg_1.style.borderBottom="2px solid white";

                }   break;
            default:
                break;          
        }

        // DEBUG
        if(debug)
        {
            debugReport
            (
                'updateSection():ID: '+msg_id+
                '<br />'+'updateSection():TIMEOUT: '+timeout+
                '<br />'+'ROTATE: '+rotate
            );
        } 
        else 
        {
            debugReset();
        }
    }
}
/*
```

Comment: If you move the `setTimeout` into the complete handler you'll only ever have one outstanding Ajax request at a time.

Comment: Hi nnn, I tried to move it, but the js still updates the messages every 10 seconds. Is there any way I can set it update every 10 secs when there is a connection, and an hour when there is no connection? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you could do something like this:

every time onerror event happens on an ajax request increment a counter. After a set limit of fails in a row / fails in an amount of time you change the length of the time-out.

```
var timeoutLength = 10000
setTimeout('updateSection(' + sect + ')', timeoutLength);
```

changing the timeoutLength once the ajax requests are failing, IE there is not internet connection.

**EDIT**

```
var errorCount = 0;

ajax.onError = whenError;

function whenError() {
  errorCount++
  if(errorCount < 5) {
    timeoutLength = 3600000
  }
}


function whenComplete() {
   errorCount = 0
   ...
}
```

This requires 5 errors in a row to assume that the internet is down. You should probably play around with that. But this should show you the general idea.

Comment: Hi Declan Cook, thanks for your reply. I changed the code as you suggested above, I still can see the js running in firebugs every 10 seconds even when i disconnected the internet. I am trying to set the updating part up every 10 seconds when there is connection, it should be every hour when there is no connection, can it be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this,

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
```

and now you can do like this,

```
if(online){
    alert('Connection is good');
}
else{
    alert('There is no internet connection');
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try to put the alert here,

```
if(online){
    setTimeout('updateSection(' + sect + ')', 10000);

    //alert('updateSection: ' + sect);
    var ajax = new sack();
    ajax.requestFile = 'ajax/getMessages.php?section=1';
    ajax.method = 'post';
    /*ajax.onError = whenError;*/
    ajax.onCompletion = whenComplete;
    ajax.runAJAX();
}
else{
    alert('There is no internet connection');
}
```

Comment: I would be careful when using this, it doesn't always mean you are not on the internet. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.onLine

Comment: Hi itsme, thanks for you reply. I did if(online){

  setTimeout('updateSection(' + sect + ')', 10000);
     }
  
  else{
  setTimeout('updateSection(' + sect + ')', 1000000);
   
  }However the js still updates the messages every 10 second even I disconnect the internet, where shall I apply your code? Sorry still learning. Thanks. Hi DECLAN COOK, can you explain a bit more on the issues to use this code? Thanks!

Comment: Put it where you request the AJAX call, I dont see in the code exactly where you request the call, but in the code you posted is it after the  setTimeout function.

Comment: Hi itsme, I have updated all my js code above. I tried your updated code, I can still see the js updates the messages when there is no internet connect in Firebugs, and there is no alert. Would you be able to have a look at my code and give me some suggestions? Thanks very much!